# Backbone js model is not getting removed from the collection in IE browser

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am displaying the list of TODO's on a screen which is nothing but a collection.
user can add/update/delete any particular model from the list.
Problem is:

---

- When user deletes all the models from the collection and only last model is remaining into that collection.
- User chooses 'Delete'.
- The last model also gets removed from the collection and also from the database at server side.
- But the last model still displays on UI list.
- This is happening only on IE browser.
- What should I do so that after removing last model from the collection I can see an empty list.

Please need help.

Comment: This issue was for IE9 and IE10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this. I have to clear the cache each time I cleared the last model from list. So I have added the ajax code for clearing the cache

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just create a new collection and do some CRUD operation in collection.

http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/